# Como fazer uma galeria com prévia dos arquivos de uma pasta/diretório?

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso montar uma galeria de prévias de arquivos, que escaneie um diretório do meu servidor e gere na página HTML uma preview de cada arquivo, onde o usuário clique e visualize a prévia, ajudando a escolher qual baixar. Alguém conhece um plugin ou função Javascript que faça isso, de modo que seja atualizada quando eu excluir ou adicionar um novo arquivo?